# Solving an operation involving roots of a quadratic equation

Tags: quadratics

A question from my book:

$3x^2 + 7x + 5 = 0$
So, $\sqrt{(x_1^2 + 2x_1x_2 + x_2^2)} + x_1x_2 = ?$

Options:
A) $4$ B) $5$ C) $6$ D) $7$ E) $8$

It's looking too easy, my answer is $-\frac{2}3$, but it does not exist in options and my book says that right answer is $4$.

Please help, where is my mistake ?

Comment: *How* did you get your answer?

Comment: I have a solution that appeals to Vieta's work, but I feel you need to go through the algebra and you will see a mistake and it is indeed 4.

Comment: $x_1^2 + 2x_1x_2 + x_2^2 = {x_1 + x_2}^2$ , so $\sqrt{x_1^2 + 2x_1x_2 + x_2^2} = x_1 + x_2$

$x_1 + x_2 = -\frac{7}{3}$
$x_1x_2 = \frac{5}{3}$
$\frac{5}{3} - \frac{7}{3} = -\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: @Oğuzİsmayiluysal: $\sqrt{a}=a$ only when $a\ge 0$. In general, $\sqrt{a}=|a|$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

$$\sqrt{x_1^2+2x_1x_2+x_2^2}+x_1x_2=\sqrt{(x_1+x_2)^2}+x_1x_2=|x_1+x_2|+x_1x_2$$

Now, use Vieta's formulas. The answer is $4$.

---

**Your mistake:** You took $\sqrt{(x_1+x_2)^2}=x_1+x_2$

But, in this case, $x_1+x_2\neq |x_1+x_2|$

Answer (score 3):

You have
$$\sqrt{x_1^2+2x_1x_2+x_2^2} + x_1x_2 = |x_1+x_2|+x_1x_2 = \left| -\frac{7}{3} \right| + \frac{5}{3} = 4$$

I think your mistake comes from ignoring that the square root of something is always nonnegative, since $-\frac{7}{3} + \frac{5}{3} = -\frac{2}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to tell you what mistake you made if you don't show your workings. However you might want to note that by convention the square root is a positive value and the sum of the roots of your original equation is negative.

Now you have edited to show $-\frac 23$ rather than $-\frac 12$ that looks likely to be the source of the difference. To avoid such problems in future ask "why have they put a square root in there, what difference does it make?"